# Ruby equivalent of PHP's ".=" (dot equals) operator

Tags: ruby, string, concatenation

In PHP we can quickly concatenate strings:

```
$a = "b";
$a .= "c";
```

which returns `"bc"`. How would we do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
irb(main):001:0> a = "ezcezc"
=> "ezcezc"
irb(main):002:0> a << "erer"
=> "ezcezcerer"
```

or

```
irb(main):003:0> a += "epruneiruv"
=> "ezcezcererepruneiruv"
```

Comment: I've seen << used is it for arrays too?

Comment: Yes it can be used in Arrays too to push a new object in to the array.

Comment: Correct, but `+=` and `<<` are different and what kind of example is that? ezxezc?

Comment: I've never been a fan of 'foos' and 'bars', monsieur :)

Answer (score 9):

There are essentially two different ways:

1. Concatenation in place with [`<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-3C-3C) (known as the "shovel"), this is equivalent to calling [`concat`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-concat). Note that, like most operators in Ruby, `<<` is a *method call*.

   ```
   str = "foo"
   str << "bar"
   str  #=> "foobar"
   ```
2. Concatenate and assign with `+=`:

   ```
   str = "foo"
   str += "bar"
   str  #=> "foobar"
   ```

   It's important to note that this is the same as:

   ```
   str = "foo"
   str = (str + "bar")
   ```

   which means that with this way *a new object is created*, while with the first way one is not, as the object is modified in place.

Comment: Much better answer. I took the liberty to edit it, as `<<` is an operator, even if it corresponds to a method call.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out:

```
string += another_string
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `string << another_string` as well