# What is the Ruby equivalent of PHP's .=

Tags: ruby, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby equivalent of PHP's “.=” (dot equals) operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706903/ruby-equivalent-of-phps-dot-equals-operator)

I want to create a variable `include_items` and keep on adding strings to it.

In PHP it would be...

```
$include_items  = "<td>first item</td>";
$include_items .= "<td>second item</td>";
$include_items .= "<td>third item</td>";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby equivalent of PHP's ".=" (dot equals) operator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9706903/211563)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try [`<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-3C-3C) and see how that works. You can also use `+=`, but that creates extra objects unnecessarily.

Answer (score 6):

[`+` is the concatenation operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-2B) for Ruby `String`s, so: **`+=`**

```
irb(main):001:0> foo = "asdf"
=> "asdf"
irb(main):002:0> foo += " and stuff"
=> "asdf and stuff"
```